# Is Julia on Visual Studio code run on windows, slow? (Julia indexing Dateframes 0%...)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, julia

I am using Julia (1.7.2) on VS code (version 1.65) run on windows 10. Start up time is really slow, showing the line: "Julia indexing Dateframes 0%...". Also package loading takes some time, not that much though. First time I came across this I just let it load, so I don't know exactly how much time it took. Tried uninstall and re-installing but came across the same problem. Anyone faced something similar? Is there something I can do to fix this? My computer details:[image: my specs]

Comment: Is this happening only the first time you add/update the package?

Comment: Did a restart on VS code and it took like 2 minutes to wrap up everything, and be ready to code, and takes about a minute and a half to run this code: `using DataFrames
using CSV
using Plots
using Lathe
using GLM
using Statistics
using StatsPlots
using MLBase`

Answer (score 0):

What I was advised to do was work in environments. Install the packages to use in an environment, and it would load faster. The problem I perceive is that you have many libraries installed, so it takes time to load.